# why would meteor be considered insecure?

Tags: javascript, meteor

perhaps an ambiguous question, but I have heard a number of people criticizing meteor as being "not secure".

I notice by default it seems to mirror nearly all information from server to client, but removing the `insecure` package seems to take care of that perfectly fine.

What aspects of Meteor are considered insecure? Is it, in fact, insecure?

Comment: One available explanation: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/

Comment: Please note that this whole insecure mess is built around one purpose: Being able to build prototypes at light-speed, you can code crap and get it to work in a matter of minutes, and build the whole prototype of an app in a couple hours. The weird, not-really-restrictive file structure is here to let you build apps like you want to build them and avoid forcing a given pattern on your face. Meteor is indeed insecure if you publish a public app with sensitive data without knowing what you're doing, but then why are you publishing an app with sensitive data in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters there is also the package `autopublish` which publishes all content in the database available for all clients. You should remove that also.
When you think about these two packages you may start to understand why people **think** that Meteor is insecure.

However there are some other problems too.

One big matter is the [file structure](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure). You have to understand it to prevent giving away all your source code. Simply put all code that is not in `/server` or `/private` is completely public and loaded in the `index.html`. Even if it wouldn't contain any keys or passwords it is still risky to distribute all you source code.

This is not based on any source but you could say that Meteor does not encourage you to trust it. With the facts above and all the stuff it does by itself you may get the feeling that it might do something that makes it vulnerable. However, as far as I know, there is no major security problems in Meteor.

Comment: isn't that kind of implied from `client/` though?

Comment: that is true :) however making your own folder e.g. `collections` doesn't imply that you would like it to be loaded in the `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Most of it is a left-over from 2012 days when Meteor first released publicly w/o any authentication or authorization built. The first release introducing the accounts system and the whole restriction system was 0.5.0 on Oct 17 2012.